# org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 85

Tags: json, kotlin, jsonexception

This is my json string :

```
{
gateway=vary, 
gateway_text=xyz, 
gateway_data=, 
start=17/02/2022 06:23:45, 
end=17/03/2022 06:23:45, 
promo_time=17/03/2022 06:23:45, 
in_process_canceled=0.0, 
id=817957632
}
```

When I am trying to convert it to JSON object, it is throwing the exception

```
val obj = JSONObject(purchaseData.toString())
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: what json library you use?

Comment: That is not JSON what you're trying to parse there, so the error is justified.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not a valid json, remove "=" and put double quotes in property and values

```
{
    "gateway": "vary",
    "gateway_text": "xyz",
    "gateway_data": "ss",
    "start": "17/02/202206:23:45",
    "end": "17/03/202206:23:45",
    "promo_time": "17/03/202206:23:45",
    "in_process_canceled": "0.0",
    "id": "817957632"
}
```

Then it will work

Comment: Is there any way to convert the same programatically

Comment: You should have a right json format, but incase if you don't have control over this output, a string replace can do the job, here you are an example:  json = json.replace(" ","").replace("\n","").replace("{", "{\"").replace("}", "\"}").replace("=", "\":\"").replace(",", "\",\""); , please mark the question as answered if this works with you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can handled by converting it to a json string ;

```
json = json.replace(" ","")
        json = json.replace("\n","")
        json = json.replace("{", "{\"")
        json = json.replace("}", "\"}")
        json = json.replace("=", "\":\"")
        json = json.replace(",", "\",\"")
val obj = JSONObject(json)
```